# Setting content dynamically inside expansion panel in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to set content dynamically inside a `mat-expansion-panel`. I have a `mat-accordion` which has a list of expansion panels. 
Here is my code:

```
<mat-accordion multi="true" *ngFor="let item of list">

    <mat-expansion-panel class="mb-3" (opened)="openPanel($event, item)">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header *ngIf="item">
            <mat-panel-title class="name" *ngIf="item.firstName ">
                <strong>{{item.firstName | textFormatter:{startIndex: 0, length: 7, noOfDots: 3, capitalize: true} }}</strong>
            </mat-panel-title>

        </mat-expansion-panel-header>

        <mat-action-row class="pl-0 pr-0">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-7" #htmlcontent>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </mat-action-row>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

On expansion of the panel, I am calling `openPanel`  method. Inside this method I want to do something like this:

`this.htmlcontent.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.item.htmlContent`

where `htmlcontent` is a `ViewChild` as follows:

`@ViewChild("htmlcontent") htmlcontent: ElementRef;`

Now the problem is I don't have a single expansion panel, but a list of them. So, I cannot set the same element `htmlcontent`. How can I set the values so that each expansion panel get different values according to the corresponding item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting it like this:

```
<div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-7" [innerHTML]="item.htmlContent"></div>
```

You should not be trying to set it when you open, it should be always set.

[Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation)